# Solve the boundary value problem $ \Delta u=1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the boundary value problem $ \Delta u=1$ for $x^2+y^2 <1$ and $u(x,y)=0$ for $x^2 + y^2 =1$ 
They gave me a hint: the solution is a simple polynomial.

Now, since i know that the solution will be a polynomial so i simply need to find such polynomial.

Consider the polynomial $Ax^2+By^2+Cxy+Dx+Ey+F$ after differentiate two time i have $$u_{xx} = 2A$$ and $$u_{yy} = 2B$$ $$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 2A + 2B = 1$$ $$A+B=1/2$$ now i think i am suppose to apply my initial conditions but i don't know how anyone that can help that will be greatly appreciate it

Comment: I suppose that initial conditions should be $u(x,y)=0$ for $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: yes, this is the boundary condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is better to start with initial conditions. Let $U(x,y) = x^2+y^2 -1$. Obviously $U(x,y) = 0$ for $x^2+y^2=1$.
Then $\Delta U(x,y) = 4$. Finally, the solution which we are looking for $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2-1)$.

Comment: How did you deduce that the laplacien of u is 4, how did you get that

Comment: Well,  $(x^2+y^2-1)_{xx} = (2x)_x = 2$, and  $(x^2+y^2-1)_{yy} = 2$. Note that I took $A=B=1$.